# Core Data Versioning - Multiple mapping models required

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an existing project that uses Core Data, and I have 3 versions within my `xcdatamodeld` bundle. So far I have only used lightweight migration as I have mostly added new parameters and entities, however I now wish to move an existing parameter into a new entity. I realise that I have to crete a `mapping model` to do this in order to get the data migrated between the parameters.

I presume there are users out there with very old versions of the app using version 1 of the model, and others using version 2 and 3.

Questions:

1. Do I need to create a mapping model from all existing versions to the new version, or just from the latest version
2. Do I need to change/disable the lightweight migration options on my `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`? Currently I have the following options enabled:

   `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption`
   `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`

I presume that lightweight migration will still be required to move from v1 to v2 to v3, however the new mapping model is required to go from v3 to v4. I've had a look around, but I can't find any information on how this all happens as most tutorials only cover 2 versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just from the latest version.
2. No.

Migrations are sequential (which is the reason why you need to keep all model versions present, even if no migration from the first version is anticipated.

The `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` will only do the automatic migration if no mapping model is present.

Comment: Maybe I'm unconfident, but where did you get this info, that Migrations are sequential? Lightweight migration only tries to update from current store model to current model in your momd file. If distant versions are incompatible for lightweight and you only have mapping model for last-1 to last - it won't work for older versions automatically!

Comment: Sorry, incompetent, not "unconfident". I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Well, this assumes (as does Apple's setup) that you cannot be sure what the earliest version of the model is out there. Therefore it is safest to include all versions, also because it hardly consumes any resources, so there is no reason *not* to include all versions.

Comment: Yes, sure, you have to include all models, but what I'm saying - simply including all models and running "addPersistentStoreWithType:..." won't automatically call migration 1-2, then 2-3, then 3-4 etc. It will try to migrate from 1 to whatever is current, 1-4, and if it's impossible to perform lightweight migration - it will fail.

Comment: Just implemented this and I had to create a mapping model from each of the possible prior versions.

Comment: Just tested: with 3 versions it will migrate automatically from version 1 or 2. As expected.

Comment: @Mundi Can you please view this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39207492/5395919